# Is it possible to load a part of google map for offline use?

Tags: android, google-maps

Can I cache or somehow save some part of google map for offline use. For, instance i need to save a city map, so in case I will not have WiFi around - my Android device will be able to load stored part of the map (with ability to zoom in/out). Is there any approaches to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a user or as a developer? As a user, yes, enable the ["Offline Caching" Maps Lab](http://lifehacker.com/5819742/google-maps-for-android-labs-add-offline-caching-scale-and-measuring-tools), but I don't think that this can be accessed via code.

Comment: I want to be able to place on offline or cached map some marks. Is it possible? As a developer.